# What causes 'Runtime Error' when using Crystal Report in ASP.NET MVC 5 project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, crystal-reports

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 project and I used Crystal Report in the project. I get this error, it's the first time I've encountered such a thing, I've been dealing with it for a few days, and I couldn't figure it out, I don't know what to do. it works fine on my computer, it gives an error after uploading to the host. Can you please help me?

Error screenshot:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94fNW.jpg)

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> *Runtime Error*
>
> Description: an application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.
>
> Details: to enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

`Web.Config` configuration file

```
<configuration> 
    <system.web> 
        <customErrors mode="Off"/> 
    </system.web> 
</configuration>
```

**Notes:** the current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's <customErrors> configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.